# Some header passing variable?

Tags: php

Im trying to pass some variables from the URL to the PHP script. Now I know that `www.site.com/index.php?link=HELLO` would require `$_GET['link']` to get the variable "link". I was hoping there are other ways to do this without the variable.

For instance I want a link structure like this: `www.site.com/HELLO`. In this example I know that I have to create a Directory called Hello place an index file and it should work but I don't want to create a directory and Im hoping there's a way to "catch" that extra part after the domain. I'm thinking of creating a custom HTTP 404 Page that will somehow get the variable of the not found page, but I don't know how to get the HTTP 404 error parameters. Is there another simpler way to get a variable without the use of the extra `?link=` part? I just want it to be a structure like this `www.site.com/HELLO`.

Comment: What you're asking for is called _URL rewriting_, and it is a common practice. It's done with Apache's mod_rewrite, for example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+rewriterule  and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is URL rewriting. You don't mention what kind of web server you're using, so I'll assume it's Apache.

If you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your web server, this can easily be accomplished by creating a `.htaccess` file in your document root with the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1
```

This will make all requests - that match the regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - get forwarded to `index.php`. For instance, if you try to access `domain.com/hello`, PHP would interpret this as trying to access `index.php?request=hello`.

You can read more about this in the [Apache HTTP Server manual about `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I tried to put this in the .htaccess file but when I do the request it gives me this error:The requested URL /site.com/index.html was not found on this server.

Comment: The current code only rewrite requests for files including a-zA-Z0-9. `index.html` contains a dot, and is therefore not rewritten. I've just updated my answer to rewrite every request, unless the requested resource exists as a file or directory.

Answer (score 2):

In which case, you normally use .htaccess to alter the URL in some form. For instance:

```
RewriteEngine On                             #Enable Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f          #If requested is not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d          #If requested is not an existing directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?link=$1 [L]    #Preform Rewrite
```

Which will make `www.site.com/hello` to `www.site.com/index.php?link=hello`. This change is invisible to the user (he will still see `www.site.com/hello` as an address). Be advised that it may cause trouble if you try using relative paths with CSS/JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL rewriting to do this. If you're using Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with a mod-rewrite structure.

Here's a pretty good tutorial on how to set it up with php/apache.

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/